# Exception in Rest Template : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/log/LogDelegateFactory

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

Method in my code :

```
public static <T> ResponseEntity<T> get(String url, HashMap<String,String> parameters, HashMap<String,String> headers, Class<T> responseType){
        System.out.println(url);
        return new RestTemplate().exchange(
            String.format("%s%s",url, toQueryString(parameters)),
            HttpMethod.GET,
            toHttpEntity(headers), responseType);
    }
```

While requesting for new object of Rest Template , it gives me below exception on -->new RestTemplate():

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/log/LogDelegateFactory
at org.springframework.http.HttpLogging.forLog(HttpLogging.java:68)
at org.springframework.http.HttpLogging.forLogName(HttpLogging.java:57)
at org.springframework.http.client.support.HttpAccessor.(HttpAccessor.java:54)
at org.springframework.http.client.support.InterceptingHttpAccessor.(InterceptingHttpAccessor.java:45)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.(RestTemplate.java:137)

dependency in pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: What does NoClassDefFoundError mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have spring core on your classpath.

Try adding

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```